# is this gereralization usecase?

Tags: architecture, uml, use-case

I have a primary usecase `Manage foods`, I want to do `more specific usecase diagram` which has these usecases `Add food`, `Delete food` and `Edit food`, so what is the relation type between those three usecases and the `Manage foods` usecase? isn't generalization?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what is the purpose of the `Manage offers` use case. What exactly does it generalise?

It would be better to get rid off `Manage offers` use case and have `Delete offer` and `Edit offer` use cases to include a `Select offer` use case.

Extension would be useful in cases similar to Stack Overflow post editing when user with low reputation would use the extended use case demanding approval.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I always have a question no one answer me , would you please check it, thanks in advance

Comment: I can't remove the `manage offers` use case becase it is a primary usecase and if i removed it , i had to replace it with `select offer` in the primary usecase , however, i made the `manage offers` include the `select offer` and make `add` is extandable by `manage offer` , what do you thing ?

Comment: Use case should produce some result. For instance `Add offer` creates a new offer - that is an obvious result. Generic `Manage offers` use case could end up in anything: new offer, deleted or modified offer. And it is not clear from the definition what it does.

Comment: I totally agree with this comment by Kimi. It is roughly the same i answered to another of your questions. Manage offers is probably not a use case. In fact, as a rule of thumb, "Manage XXX" should never be a use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, you should remove usecase "Manage Offers" from model and leave only Delete, Edit and Add offer usecases. This three usecases should represent services included in "Offer Management" of you application.